# Where do I put the mezuzah if I have a screen door before the front door?

Tags: mezuzah

I recently installed a screen door in front of my front door.  Do I have to move the mezuzah to be outside the screen door?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a reference that says that the mezuzah can be left in between the screen door and the main door. Of course, CYLOR (Consult Your Local Orthodox Rabbi) and have him check the actual set up of your doors as it may be different from the answers cited.

[Ask The Sofer](http://www.mezuzah.net/sofer.html)

> 18. Question:
>
> I am moving from an apartment to a house. The house has a screen door.
>   Then a regular wooden door. Should the mezuzah be placed between the
>   two doors?
>
> Regarding the main entrance:
>
> It's preferable to place the outer mezuzah between the two doors than
>   to put it on the outside of the home.
>
> 115. Question:
>
> I am sorry if you have already answered this question, I just haven't
>   seen it. My front door has the door and then a screen door should I
>   place the mezuzah completly outside or should it go in the "space"
>   between the front door and the screen door?
>
> Thank you, Devorah
>
> Answer:
>
> Dear Devorah,
>
> It's best for the mezuzah to be close to the outer edge of the
>   doorway. Whether it's between the doors or outside of both doors
>   doesn't matter, as long as it's within a "tefach" (8 centimeters or
>   3.1 inches) of the outer edge of the doorway.
>
> Best wishes, Eliyahu
>
> 191. Question:
>
> Dear Rabbi,
>
> I have just moved into a flat that has a screen door. The actual
>   doorpost is between the screen door and the proper door. The screen
>   doorframe sits flush with the outside wall.
>
> So where do I hang the mezuzah?
>
> Thank you for your kind assistance.
>
> Warm regards,
>
> Dara
>
> Answer:
>
> Dear Dara,
>
> The mezuzah should be on the doorpost, between the screen door and the
>   proper door.
>
> Best wishes,

Comment: In other words, the mezuzah goes on the doorpost of your house. The screen door's post is not the one to your house.

Comment: @DanF  That is the way the references seem to be. Usually, the screen door is mounted on the same post as the main door, but on the outside.

Comment: I didn't think of that. I wonder if it makes a difference when the two doors swing in opposite directions, as most likely occurs in this scenario. Usually screen doors swing outward and house doors swing inward.